# Where can I find standard aviation abbreviations for the "unit of measure"?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I have been in the aviation industry specialising in Logistics all my life.  There used to be a standard, the ATA 200, for how to abbreviate the unit of measures, such a EA for each, KG for kilograms, HU for hundred, and so on.  I understand that the ATA 200 is now dead and has been replaced by ATA Spec 2000 but I can not find these abbreviations in the Spec 2000.

I suppose that these abbreviations are still valid but where can I find them?

Comment: Hello Erik, welcome to Aviation.SE!

Answer (score 3):

This is defined in [ICAO Annex 5 - Units of Measurement to be Used in Air and Ground Operations](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjskcPmz4HOAhUBnywKHQEWBtoQFghAMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bazl.admin.ch%2Fdam%2Fbazl%2Ffr%2Fdokumente%2FFachleute%2FRegulationen_und_Grundlagen%2F111%2Ficao_annex_5_unitsofmeasurementtobeusedinairandgroundoperations.pdf.download.pdf%2Ficao_annex_5_unitsofmeasurementtobeusedinairandgroundoperations.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFtU6WHp1HR_ReoMUwagjqlkU0vPA&sig2=yJ42cCikGbfN96Kzm4zQGQ)